# Vector Multiplied with a Scalar - Correct Notation?

Tags: notation, vectors

I came across an exercise from the textbook *The Fundamentals of Physics* by Halliday which is as follows:

> Which of the following are correct (meaningful) vector expressions? What is wrong with any incorrect expression?
>
> a) $\vec{A} \cdot (\vec{B} \cdot \vec{C})$

The solution states that this is false, because "cannot dot a vector with a scalar".

However, I learned that I can multiply a vector with a scalar (by multiplying its magnitude with the scalar and rotating the vector by $\pi$ radians if the scalar is negative). As $\vec{B} \cdot \vec{C}$ yields a scalar, why should I not be able to multiply that scalar with the vector $\vec{A}$?

Or is there maybe a different notation for multiplying a vector with a scalar that I am missing?

Comment: Presumably Halliday did not use $\cdot$ for multiplication.

Comment: I would write $\vec A\,(\vec B\cdot\vec C)$. Not $\cdot$, even less $\times$.

Comment: It all comes down to notation and conventions.  I personally find people writing $\lambda \vec{v}$ all the time to represent the vector $\vec{v}$ multiplied by the scalar $\lambda$ with no symbol inbetween to indicate the multiplication but rarely see it the other way around as $\vec{v}\lambda$.  I don't necessarily see it as wrong to indicate it as $\lambda\cdot \vec{v}$ in the same way that I don't necessarily see it as wrong to indicate multiplication of real numbers in the same way as multiplication of matrices.  The same symbol can be used for multiple meanings depending on context.